# Convert uploadfile to uploadfileasync c#

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

Hello I'm trying to upload a file to my web server via c# and I'm having a problem when uploading the file my application freezes until file is done uploading and I wanted to upload it Async but I cannot seem to get the code to work here is there code and the error I keep getting.

This code works but freezes the form.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(TxtUsername.Text, TxtPassword.Text);
string Filename = TxtFilename.Text;
string Server = TxtServer.Text + SafeFileName.Text;
wc.UploadFile(Server, Filename);
```

But if i do this code I get an error.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(TxtUsername.Text, TxtPassword.Text);
string Filename = TxtFilename.Text;
string Server = TxtServer.Text + SafeFileName.Text;
wc.UploadFileAsync(Server, Filename);
```

and I get this error when trying to make it Async

```
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for System.Net.WebClient.UploadFileAsync(System.Uri, string)' has some invalid arguments.
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Uri'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the line

```
wc.UploadFileAsync(Server, Filename);
```

to

```
wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(Server), Filename);
```

`UploadFileAsync` does not take a string argument, so you need to create a `Uri` from the server address.  See the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144232.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

As Kami said. Furthermore, you might want to handle the `UploadFileCompleted` event.

Example:

```
wc.UploadFileCompleted += (o, args) =>
{
    //Handle completition
};
wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(Server), Filename);
```